# Error using getContex and ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() after update AS

Tags: android

I have updated my Android Studio to 3.4.1 and Im using target sdk version 28 . I run my previous project. Now I got many errors : getContex or ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() is not defined. 
UPDATE: here is the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol method getContext()
error: cannot find symbol method shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity,String)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try re-syncing your project or clean project?

Comment: yes I did, I also Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Please post the error you get while building your project

Comment: sure, I update my question

Answer (score 0):

`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Context context, String permission)` method is used simply for checking whether you are having requested permission available for your app or not.

If your app needs a dangerous permission, you must check whether you have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires that permission. Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level.

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity activity, String[] permissions,int reqCode)` method is used for requesting permissions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers.I add `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` to build.gradle. Before it I just have `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` and It works.